# unable to dynamically change content of div on button on click

Tags: jquery

I want to add string `content` inside a `div` but my code isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getContentOfAreas() {
    console.log("will add content");
    $('#preview').InnerHtml = "content";
    }
</script>
<div id="preview" style="height:100px;border:1px solid black"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="getContentOfAreas()">click me to see content</button>
```

Comment: well, JS is a case-sensitive language, so `InnerHtml` is different from `innerHTML`, which is the correct nomenclature

Comment: Also, jQuery method for setting HTML is `.html("content here")` and not `.innerHTML = "content here"` (that is for vanilla JS)

Answer (score 0):

[innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) is vanilla JavaScript, since you're already using jQuery, you can just use the [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/) method.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getContentOfAreas() {
      console.log("will add content");
      $('#preview').html("content");
    }
</script>
<div id="preview" style="height:100px;border:1px solid black"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="getContentOfAreas()">click me to see content</button>
```